# HTML 5 form plug in with real-time validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, html

I am looking for a JQuery plugin similar to [this](http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/ajax-jquery-validation-html5-form.html), to allow html5 form support across browsers. However, I am looking for one that implements real-time form validation. Giving users feedback either on keyup or on blur (preferably blur).

Does anyone know something that fits the bill?

Comment: It's a sound question, one that I'd be interested in.  Unfortunately I did my best Google-fu and haven't found anything. :(  Sounds like a great opportunity to write your own or customize the one you linked to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget my comment, I found this: http://ericleads.com/h5validate/ !

Does that suit your needs?

> focusout, focusin, change, keyup
>   (Events) These are the "keyboard
>   oriented" events. Better to think of
>   them as non-mouse-specific events. Set
>   them to "true" if you want them to
>   trigger a field validation. Defaults:

```
focusout: true, 
focusin: false,
change: false, 
keyup: true
```

Comment: That's too good... I tore up google before I came here too, and couldn't find anything. Then found that same link you sent just before returning here. :)