# HTC One X KeyCode always returns zero

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events, htc-android

I have a need to validate text entered into a `textbox` using JavaScript before it's sent off to a third party to be acted upon.

To do this, I'm using the `browserEvent.keyCode` parameter to get the `keycode` sent to the browser on the key-up event, then validating the code to say whether it's allowed in the `textbox` or not.

This works fine across all devices I've tested, apart from Chrome on the HTC One X.

I've found annoying differences between various Android and iOS devices, but they all return something that I can work with. The HTC One X, however, returns `0` with every key press apart from the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys, which return `8` and `13` respectively.

I've tried `event.keyCode`, `event.charCode` and `event.which` as well as `browserEvent.keyCode`, `browserEvent.charCode`and `browserEvent.which` codes, and everything is returned as a `0`.

Basically, I'm stuck. Does anyone have any idea

1. why the `keycode` is always returned as `0` on this device, and
2. how I can detect the `keycode`?

Comment: Sounds like you're validating input-text by checking the keycodes... not the actual text.

Comment: +1 for hippo, I love hippos  :-)

Comment: @Lukas, yep, I am. It's purely because the code is already written like that and it's been tested on around 20 mobile devices, and we know it works. If I have to re-write it to check the value entered into the text input, then I'm looking at regression testing across all devices to make sure the new way works. We also did have problems actually checking the input (which I can't remember at the moment), so checking character codes was seen to be the best way of accomplishing the validation

Comment: Well, it seems to work on *some* devices, you don't know how many are not supported. Also, I imagine this to be a very big, ugly pile of code. Why not create a simple RegEx to validate the input?

Comment: @LukasKnuth Just remembered. One of the requirements of the specification was that invalid characters couldn't be entered into the text input (I don't know why). Because of that, we can't do validation only on submission, so a filter style function called on the key-up event was deemed the best course of action. What you're suggesting makes sense though, and I don't see any reason why I can't capture a keycode of 0 then apply some regex and either allow the input or reset it based on the last character entered.

Comment: Seems there are plugins to do stuff like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748183/html-5-form-plug-in-with-real-time-validation

Comment: @LukasKnuth Cheers man, that link looks good. Unfortunately because this is a mobile app, we don't want to include any external libraries to keep the footprint small. We don't use jquery because of the size of the library, all of our JavaScript functionality is custom written.

Comment: Hm, maybe you can still steal stuff from that plugin. Putting that aside, I would (if real-time validation is mandatory) re-validate against the RegEx on every key-down event. If your input isn't too long and your RegEx not too complicated, this should be fine.

Comment: @LukasKnuth That's essentially what I did. I've answered the question myself, but I feel like I've stolen your answer points in doing so. If you want to put that last comment as an answer, I'll quite happily mark it as the answer I went with.

Comment: Nah, it's fine. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't answer the immediate question, I used some of the ideas Lukas Knuth gave me to solve it.

The process is now that a keycode of 0 is caught and handed to a function that runs the contents of the input box through some Regex validation. If the validation fails, then the last character is removed from the input box.

I apologise if anyone comes to this question seeking a solution for the HTC One X passing through 0 as the keycode, after a couple of days of research and experimentation, I couldn't find a solution, so I worked around the problem instead.